# checkboxGroupInput in Shiny doesn't work when input data is data table not data frame

Tags: shiny, datatable

I have a case where I need to view a data table in Shiny with dynamic user-selected columns to view. [This](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html) demo in Shiny Gallery was very insightful as a start. But when I applied it to my specific code where I use a data table rather than a data frame the main panel throws an error of "'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)". The only reason I got figure out for this error is that the input$show_vars does not work when the input data is a data table.

I present here two samples of codes to show the problem. The first one works well when the diamonds data is a data frame. The other one is the same code but the diamonds table is converted in data table in server section.

Appreciate any assistance to fix the code such that it works well when the input data is data table class.

**Scenario1:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
        )
      )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
  output$mytable1 <-  renderDataTable({
    diamonds2[, input$show_vars]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
`
```

**Scenario2:**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
        )
      )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = as.data.table(diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ])
  output$mytable1 <-  renderDataTable({
    diamonds2[, input$show_vars]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data.table` *sees column names as if they are variables*, you need to tell your `data.table` that `input$show_vars` is an environment variable, not a column name, using `..var`:

> `..var` tells `data.table` to look for `var` in the calling environment as
> opposed to a column of the table

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1

Also, since `input` is a `reactiveValue`, you should save `input$show_vars` as a vector so `data.table` can interpret it correctly:

```
  output$mytable1 <-  renderDataTable({
    columnsSelected <- input$show_vars
    diamonds2[, ..columnsSelected]
  })
```